# Draw customized (calculus) graphs like these?

Tags: calculus, math-software, graphing-functions

Can you please suggest some good software to draw customized graphs like these?

PS:I am studying calculus (engineering degree) and would like to take notes on my pc, including customized graphs, about all the theorems I am learning (bolzano-weierstrass, Rolle, etc...).

Hope you can help.

Thanks.

NB: I am on windows, but can use linux software as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is not actually graph theory. (I wasn't sure whether to flag this for moderator attention; if a mod sees this, can you let me know?)

Comment: Not sure whether to flag it, but I have enough rep to retag stuff so I got rid of the graph-theory tag.

Comment: I do not understand how we can have 4 different questions on graphing software, and none of them have mentioned the same ones. See also (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26903/what-is-a-good-graphing-software) and (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/software-for-plotting-a-graph).

Answer (score 7):

[GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/) is easy to use, free, and the graphs look good.

Comment: +1 What an excellent piece of software.  Wish that had been around long ago when I was studying.

Comment: @Eivind: I tried inputing this: $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=2z(x^2+y^2)$. Does it more than 3d graphing?

Comment: @Cplayer: I have only used it for simple 2D graphing (for functions of one variable), and I don't think it can draw graphs of higher dimension. At least not the version I'm using.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, Eiving. so how can I draw the green curve, in my figure no.1 ? I can't find the right tool in geogebra.

Comment: @iAsk: At the bottom of the window, there is a line where you can write your function, for example $y=\cos (x)$.

Comment: Thanks Eiving, but i don't know the equation of the green line/curve in my fig.1 . so how can i draw it manually? I can't find a way...thank you :)

Comment: @iAsk: If that was what you wanted (to draw it manually), I misunderstood your question, and I don't know any way to do this in geogebra. In any case, it is not usually that hard to find expressions for functions that looks similar to the ones you want, and which is good enough for your use, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: For example: For the first (and the third, i guess) you can use a part of a sine/cosine function, and for the second there are plenty of functions to choose from (for instance $-x^2$).

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.onlinefunctiongrapher.com/. You can customize your graphs there. Easy to use and free! unlike Mathematica or Mathlab. It is online so you don't have to worry about linux/windows shift.

Comment: Look at the [section of the FAQ on self-promotion](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). All three of your posts on this site so far have been to promote your website, and none have disclosed your affiliation. If this continues the moderators may have to take action.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a Mac or iPad, this might help:
  http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraphsketcher/

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up from time to time in different forms. In an effort to consolidate all this information, check out the following.

See also [What is a good graphing software?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26903/what-is-a-good-graphing-software) and [Software for plotting a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55570/software-for-plotting-a-graph)

Perhaps also [A good, free, graphics package for mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5837/a-good-free-graphics-package-for-mathematics) and [Educational Math Software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/educational-math-software)