# Software for plotting a graph

Tags: math-software

I have an excel file with 8083 X and Y columns.

The first column represents the name of the image I have, and the other column represents the multiplicaltion reusult of the (x,y) resolution of that image (i.e; (512,512) -> 262144.

Now, in this case, I will have an image name and a result beside it.

I'm trying to plot a graph that gives me the number of images that equal for example 262144.

So, I will have an x-axis with representing the "resolution" multiplication result, and a "y-axis" representing the "Number of images".

Is there a software program that enables me to get such graph? Provided that, again, I have 8083 records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) vector graphics language. Check out the gallery of graphs/plots/sketches.

[image: Histogram Example]

"Here is a histogram example, which uses the stats module."

```
 import graph;
 import stats;

 size(400,200,IgnoreAspect);

 int n=10000;
 real[] a=new real[n];
 for(int i=0; i < n; ++i) a[i]=Gaussrand();

 draw(graph(Gaussian,min(a),max(a)),blue);

 // Optionally calculate "optimal" number of bins a la Shimazaki and Shinomoto.
 int N=bins(a);

 histogram(a,min(a),max(a),N,normalize=true,low=0,lightred,black,bars=false);

 xaxis("$x$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
 yaxis("$dP/dx$",LeftRight,RightTicks(trailingzero));
```

Example [link](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/graph.html) (scroll to about 80% of the page).

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to do in Excel, since you seem to want to plot a huge amount of points, e.g. it could look like

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
...
262144 1
...
```

which will be a very long list.

You can do it in [R](http://www.r-project.org/) quite easily.  For example

```
> x = 1:8083
> y = 2:8084
> z = x*y
> t = table(z)
> plot(t)
```

would draw a rather cramped plot.  Here x takes the values 1, 2, ..., 8083 and y takes the values 2, 3, ..., 8084.

Another example is:

```
> x = c(1, 100, 512)
> y = c(555, 444, 512)
> z = x*y
> t = table(z)
> plot(t)
```

Here x takes the values 1, 100, 152 whereas y takes the values 555, 444, 512.  Here's what the output would look like:

[image: R output]

However, I don't really understand why you would want to plot this.  If you're just after the number of data points in which x*y = 262144 (or some other number), then you can use an indicator variable in Excel, as I have done in the following example:

[image]

Here I entered

```
=IF($D3=E$11,1,0)
```

into cell E3, then dragged it along through to cell G9.  I manually entered the numbers in cells E11, F11 and G11.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look at R? -- it has tools for binning & counting, and I gather that's what you need to do. Here's a link
[histograms in R](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/degrees/modules/ch923/r_introduction/histograms_etc/). Another alternative might be [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).